# Cannot get my simple JavaScript function to work

Tags: javascript, function

Hi I am new to the site so I hope this goes well but I have an image and when I click on it I want a function to run to show a  but no matter what I try it will not do anything... I am new to JavaScript so I assume something is wrong.

Can anyone help?

This is the JavaScript I am using between the  tags!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showLarge() {
    var largeFrame = document.getElementById(zoomedIn);
    largeFrame.style.visibility='visible';
    }
</script>
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="zoomedIn" style="visibility:hidden">

<img src="Media//Gallery//img_1.jpg" onclick="showLarge();" alt="Gallery Image 1" />
```

Comment: Please read up on the basics of JS before attempting it, it'll save you lots of time in the long run :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps

```
var largeFrame = document.getElementById("zoomedIn");
```

would work?

Comment: Yeah that worked thank you very much! Great quick response.

Comment: Why people don't click and accept right answers as right answers?